# MobileFirst Push Notification Proxy - 407 Proxy Authentication Error

Tags: push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, ibm-mobilefirst, http-proxy

I'm trying to configure IBM MobileFirst push notifications via Proxy (It was working without Proxy). Below Worklight.properties "GCM Proxy" config:

```
push.gcm.proxy.enabled=true
push.gcm.proxy.protocol=HTTP
push.gcm.proxy.host=192.168.250.21
push.gcm.proxy.port=80
push.gcm.proxy.user=
push.gcm.proxy.password=
```

Kindly, note that there is no required authentication with proxy.

However, I'm getting below error:

*FPWSE1055E: Failed to invoke Google GCM push service.
com.ibm.pushworks.server.exceptions.GCMException: GCM Service invocation Failed (reason: Unexpected response code HTTP/1.1 407 Proxy Authentication Required when invoking Google GCM push service.*

Comment: I think the answer is in the question.

Answer (score 0):

This **error 407** is similar to **401 - Unauthorized**, but indicates that the client should first authenticate with a proxy server. You can check this related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2131933/http-407-proxy-authentication-error-when-calling-a-web-service). This is a very common error message when you try to get a resource on internet through your application. The reason why you're getting this error from your application not from explorer is either you use LAN that requires proxy setting or you use proxy server.